# What is load balancing in php and how it is done?

Tags: php, load-balancing

> I want to know about what is load balancing and how it is done in php.
>   how load balancing is done in php.

Comment: Load balancing is done on server .. It is  part of server administration

Comment: Note that the SO community is not a replacement for doing your own research / google searches.

Comment: ohhh then what you say how it is done on server any way you suggest buddy @MASIDDIQUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load balancing is dividing the amount of work that a server has to do between two or more servers (known as server farm or server pool) so that more work gets done in the same amount of time and, in general, all users get served faster.

Load balancing can be implemented with hardware, software, or a combination of both.

Typically, load balancing is mainly associated with servers.

Refer to this link for more https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/

Answer (score 1):

Load balancing refers to efficiently distributing incoming network traffic across a group of backend servers, also known as a server farm or server pool.

Server Administrators take care of load balancing via various tools.